# Name of color setting for selected XAML statement

Tags: visual-studio, xaml, editor, color-scheme

When I click on an element in Visual Studio's XAML designer, VS adds a faint highlight to the corresponding XAML statement in the XAML text editor (as seen for StackPanel below). What's this highlight called in Visual Studio's Fonts and Colors customization settings? I want to change it but it's hiding itself well.

[image]

Comment: I think it's just Fonts & Colors->Active Statement->Background

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't do the trick for me.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It should be Tools->Options->Fonts and Colors->Text Editor->Brace Matching (Rectangle).

> So that's technically the correct answer to my question because it does indeed work when I click in the XAML editor. But unfortunately it's revealed a misunderstanding in my question. What I'm actually looking for is the color setting name for the highlight when I click on an element in the XAML designer, which then highlights the XAML statement as seen in the screenshot above.

Try Tools->Options->Fonts and Colors->Text Editor->Inactive Selected Text then.

Comment: So that's technically the correct answer to my question because it does indeed work when I click in the XAML editor. But unfortunately it's revealed a misunderstanding in my question. What I'm actually looking for is the color setting name for the highlight when I click on an element in the XAML designer, which then highlights the XAML statement as seen in the screenshot above. And it turns out that that highlight is not the same as the Brace Matching one :( I updated the question text.

Comment: I might be blind, but I don't see that entry in VS2015. I see "Identifier" and then the next available setting is "Inline Rename".

Comment: It should be listed as the third item from the top in the "Display items:" ListBox.

Comment: Got it. I assumed all settings would be listed alphabetically.

Comment: That was driving me nuts.  Would have never guessed that one. Thanks.